# Traer lista de tabla con relaciones EF C# asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tengo las siguientes relaciones en SQL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las 3 estan relacionadas por el campo `factura`, la cuestión es que en que estoy ingresando un número de factura y quiero que me traiga primero los datos de la tabla `Materiales`y despues de las otras 2 (quiero hacerlo asi uno a uno porque no se como llamar todo en conjunto).

Como no se llamarlas en conjunto quiero traer primero este dato (ejemplo) de mi tabla `Materiales`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO PARA TRAER LOS DATOS**

```
//TRAER CABEZA DE LA FACTURA
 public List<Materiale> dataUnica(string fac)
 {
    var lista = new List<Materiale>();

    using(var ctx=new ModelContext())
    {
       lista = ctx.Materiales.Where(x => x.factura == fac)
                             .ToList();
     }

     return lista;
  }
```

**CODIGO DONDE PASO LOS DATOS AL AJAX DE VUELTA**

```
[HttpGet]
public string getFacturaData(string ff)
{
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mT.dataUnica(ff));
}
```

En la linea del JSON estoy teniendo el siguiente error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error getting value from
>   'Det_mate2' on
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Materiale_5B9A5C2FF9BBF9788B0E565D9631BB85E36ED4F9804447E308EBA79DAB4A36A8'.'
>   ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed
>   and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

**CODIGO DE LA TABLA `MATERIALE`**

```
 public partial class Materiale
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Materiale()
        {
            Det_materiales = new HashSet<Det_materiales>();
            Det_mate2 = new HashSet<Det_mate2>();
        }

        [Key]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string factura { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Invoice { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime fecha { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string tipo_via { get; set; }

        public double pesobruto { get; set; }

        public double pesoneto { get; set; }

        public int numerobultos { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Det_materiales> Det_materiales { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Det_mate2> Det_mate2 { get; set; }
}
```

Siento que esta jalando los datos de la otras tablas usando el numero de factura por eso el error (desde mi ignorancia) como evito esto, para solo jalar los datos de la tabla `Materiales`?

Comment: Podes intentar deshabilitando lazyloading? Da la impresión que quiere obtener más información tras perder conexión con el context

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal y como hago eso? Perdona la pregunta

Comment: `ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` inmediatamente después del using

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Me sirvio, muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Serialización y la carga diferida no mezclan bien y, si no tiene cuidado puede acabar consultar toda la base de datos simplemente porque está habilitada la carga diferida. La mayoría de los serializadores funcionan mediante el acceso a cada propiedad en una instancia de un tipo. Acceso a la propiedad desencadena la carga diferida, por lo que se serializan más entidades. En esas entidades se tiene acceso a las propiedades y se cargan entidades aún más. Es una buena práctica para activar carga desactivado antes de serializar una entidad diferida.Las secciones siguientes muestran cómo hacerlo.

[Serializacion Lazy Loanding](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#turn-lazy-loading-off-for-serialization)

Eso ocurre cuando usas lazy loading y agregas virtual a tus propiedades. Para solucionar esto tienes que usar un método de carga explicito con el metodo `include`.

Primero desactivar lazy loading:

```
public class TuContexto : DbContext 
{ 
  public TuContexto()       
  { 
  this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
  } 
}
```

Y eliminas el virtual de estas propiedades:

```
 [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")] 
public ICollection<Det_materiales> Det_materiales { get; set; } 
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")] 
public ICollection<Det_mate2> Det_mate2 { get; set; }
```

Entonces para cargar tus facturas

```
var materialesConFacturas = ctx.Materiales.Include(x => x.Factura).ToList();
// Esto obtiene todos los materiales con sus facturas
```

Entonces tienes que especificar que propiedad vas cargar en el método `include`esto te solucionara globalmente el problema de serialización y cargar las relaciones solo cuando la necesites te ayudara en el rendimiento.